# ¿Cual es la mejor y más eficiente manera de hacer un login?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tengo un login que me funciona perfecto hasta el momento, pero quiero saber si estoy cometiendo errores de seguridad y de eficiencia.

Mi JS:

```
    function iniciarSesion() {
    var usuario = document.getElementById("txtusuario").value;
    var clave = document.getElementById("txtclave").value;

    var datos = {
        "usuario": usuario,
        "clave": clave
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "./model/usuario.php?dato=leerusuario",
        type: 'POST',
        data: datos,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (respuesta) {
            if (respuesta.usuario === usuario) {
                var pagina = "http://localhost/BERLINUXERP/index.php";
                document.location.href = pagina;
            } else {
                $('#alertclaveinvalida').show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

MI PHP:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();

    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $preclave = $_POST['clave'];

    $clave = md5($preclave);

    $sql = " SELECT u_alias, u_nombre, u_clave, r_nombre, r_clase, rp_id, rp_nombre "
            . " FROM usuario, rol_x_usuario, roles, rol_padre "
            . " WHERE u_alias = :usuario AND u_clave = :clave AND "
            . "  rxu_usuario = u_alias AND r_id = rxu_rol AND rxu_permitido = TRUE AND r_id != 1 AND rp_id = r_padre
                 ORDER BY rp_id ";

    $info = array();
    $roles = array();
    $usuarioEncontrado = false;

    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->bindParam(":clave", $clave, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $q->execute();

    $resultado = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($resultado as $row) {
        if ($usuarioEncontrado == false) {
            session_start();
            $info['usuario'] = $row['u_alias'];
            $info['clave'] = $row['u_clave'];
            $info['nombre'] = $row['u_nombre'];

            array_push($roles, array("rol" => $row['r_nombre'],
                "clase" => $row['r_clase'],
                "rol_padre_id" => $row['rp_id'],
                "rol_padre" => $row['rp_nombre']));

            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['u_nombre'];
            $_SESSION['alias'] = $row['u_alias'];

            $usuarioEncontrado = true;
        } else {
            array_push($roles, array("rol" => $row['r_nombre'],
                "clase" => $row['r_clase'],
                "rol_padre_id" => $row['rp_id'],
                "rol_padre" => $row['rp_nombre']));
        }
    }

    if ($usuarioEncontrado) {
        $_SESSION['roles'] = $roles;
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);
    }

    Database::disconnect();
    echo json_encode($info);
    break;
```

Tengo entendido que no se debe hacer esto:

```
var pagina = "http://localhost/BERLINUXERP/index.php";
```

Porque al momento que lo suba a un servidor no va a encontrarla página, la idea es que navegue dentro del directorio con un:

```
header("Location: login.php");
```

Pero el momento de incluirlo en este if, no me funciona:

```
if ($usuarioEncontrado) {
    $_SESSION['roles'] = $roles;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

No soy experto en PHP y JS, pero quiero saber que tan desastroso está mi código y cómo lo puedo mejorar en seguridad y eficiencia, también para corregir el redireccionamiento.